# Spring Integration: Stop a flow gracefully and avoid MessageDispatchingException

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

My program have to be able to stop and start it again one or another flow.
I do it with integrationFlowRegistration.stop() / .start() methods.
The problem is that wenn Lifecycle components are stopped hundreds of MessageDispatchingException's are thrown.
Probably because some components are stopped and another are still trying to deliver some messages.
Is there some best practice to stop the flow?
Some standard way to block flow.inputChannel, wait until all channels have no messages to deliver and then stop all components of the flow?
Below is junit test to reproduce this behavior.

```
@Test
public void testStopFlowGracefully() {
    final Queue<List<Integer>> inQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    MessageSource<List<Integer>> inMs = new AbstractMessageSource<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public String getComponentType() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doReceive() {
            return inQueue.poll();
        }
    };

    QueueChannel resultChannel = new QueueChannel();

    IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(inMs, c->c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(50)))
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)))
            .<Integer, Integer>transform(p -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) { }                   
                return p * 2;})
            .log(l -> "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! transformed int="+l)
            .channel(resultChannel)
            .get();

    IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = this.flowContext.registration(integrationFlow).register();

    inQueue.add(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    registration.stop();

    Message<?> msg = resultChannel.receive(2000);
    assertThat(msg).isNotNull();
}
```

Comment: I have just copied/pasted your test-case and it passes for me well. What am I missing ?

Comment: What Spring Integration version do you use?

Comment: Yes the test passes well but there are a lot of MessageDispatchingExceptions thrown. In my production code there are many 1000. The whole log file will be written full by stopping a flow.

Comment: I use Spring Boot 2.0 and so Spring Integration 5.0.3 If you do not see any exceptions try to play with milliseconds in Thread.sleep(...) methods. Probably you have better computer as my workhorse

Comment: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)` - you have async components and an unbounded task queue; the framework knows nothing about the queue within that executor. You need to stop the inbound channel adapter and wait for the queue to drain. It would also be better if the task executor was managed by Spring.

Comment: I do use Spring managed task executor in my production code. Is there some smart way to stop JdbcPollingChannelAdapter (it is my inbound channel adapter)? Some event interceptor?

Comment: Well, I think you just don't show something else from your application. The `IntegrationFlow` you show in the question is fully out of `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` and my point that it stops gracefully. When we call its `stop()` all the components in the flow are stopped from top to bottom. Therefore `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` for the `inMs` is stopped first and doesn't produce messages any more. I guess your `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` is out of the such a dynamic `IntegrationFlow` and stopping the flow doesn't affect `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`

Comment: Also keep in mind. When you use `try...catch` around some `throws InterruptedException` method like `Thread.sleep(100)`, you have to call `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` and re-throw exception.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I think you both have right. My junit code is not 100% equal to the production case. If I comment out .log() in junit, I do not get any exceptions anymore. This is not the case in production. I commented out all .log() methods there but still have got the exception. So I think in this case Gary has nailed the problem. Because my JdbcPollingChannelAdapter reads the keys of the entities that were modified since last iteration. And it could be really many of them. Then I use .split() and process them asynch. And exceptions are probably coming from worker threads.